# Good tutorials on profiling and speeding up bottlenecks in python with C/C++

Tags: python

looking to learn more about the above. Any recommendations for packages and tutorials about the above ?

Answer (score 2):

The Python [extension](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example) documentation does a pretty good job of describing how to create C-extensions for your bottlenecks.